# Project component - what exactly is this?

Tags: pm-software, tools

In order to better track issues and plan development of an ever-expanding web application, I am setting up an instance of `Trac`.   As developer, I will use this system primarily, along with the department coordinator and a few end-users.

Most of the `Trac` configuration is relatively self-explanatory, however I am a little unsure how to use the `components` option (on the ticket form).

Should I include components of the application itself (ie, product page, user administration, reports, ect) or is this field designed for higher level objects (such as users, coordinators, developers) or something else entirely?

I will be using Trac to keep track of bugs, regular maintenance, server maintenance, and new development among other things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well based on Trac's website docs...
"Component — The project module or subsystem this ticket concerns."

[The Trac Ticket System](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracTickets)

Hope that helps.

Comment: That's what I assumed, but I wanted to make sure I'm using the field correctly - in a project management sense.

Comment: from a PM point of view? their definition makes sense. As a PM I can compare fixes vs. new dev on the component in case some prioritization is needed.